# Display Wordpress menu on specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 menus that I've registered in my `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'visio' ) );
    register_nav_menu( 'onepage', __( 'One Page Menu', 'visio' ) );
}
```

The `One Page Menu` should only display on the frontpage, which is using a custom page template `template-parts/page-homepage.php`

And the `Primary Menu` should display on all other pages.

However, when I create the if condition in my `header.php` - it doesn't work, it always displays the `One Page Menu` on the frontpage and on all other pages.

```
if(is_page_template('template-parts/page-homepage.php')) {
    wp_nav_menu(
        array (
            'menu'            => 'onepage',
            'container'       => false,
            'container_id'    => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'menu_id'         => false,
            'depth'           => 2,
            'walker'          => new Description_Walker
        )
    );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu(
        array (
            'menu'            => 'primary',
            'container'       => false,
            'container_id'    => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'menu_id'         => false,
            'depth'           => 2,
            'walker'          => new Description_Walker
        )
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? And how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways that comes to my mind.

> 1) Using separate header.php template for home page and other page .
>
> 2) Using menu location settings .
>
> 3) Using setting options and according to them display the menu

But with your code I think you should try replace `is_page_template('template-parts/page-homepage.php')` with

```
is_page_template('page-homepage.php')
```

As

is_page_template() is not going for directory .

```
function is_page_template( $template = '' ) {
    if ( ! is_page() )
        return false;

    $page_template = get_page_template_slug( get_queried_object_id() );

    if ( empty( $template ) )
        return (bool) $page_template;

    if ( $template == $page_template )
        return true;

    if ( is_array( $template ) ) {
        if ( ( in_array( 'default', $template, true ) && ! $page_template )
            || in_array( $page_template, $template, true )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return ( 'default' === $template && ! $page_template );
}
```

2 ) When using menu location setting you can use

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'pluginbuddy_mobile' => 'PluginBuddy Mobile Navigation Menu',
    'footer_menu' => 'My Custom Footer Menu',
) );
```

and

```
  <?php
    if ( has_nav_menu( 'footer_menu' ) ) {
         wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer_menu' ) );
    } ?>
```

to control the display of menu.

3) With setting options you can do something use `update_option()` and `get_option()` .

Comment: Using `is_page_template('page-homepage.php')` doesn't work either. Mind explaining how I can use the menu location settings or the settings options?

Comment: @Halnex I have updated my answer to add little more detail about my idea of doing it, please go through it and let me know if you have still any query .

Comment: @Halnex I am glad that I am able to help you.