# How to show Wordpress secondary menu only on certain page?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have added my secondary menu on my function.php file and WordPress also allowed me to choose the secondary menu. The problem is both menu bar appeared at the same time so i have double menu bar on the top of my home page and also my about us page. What I'm try to do is show my primary menu bar only in my main home page, and show secondary menu on my about us page, services page, etc...  How can i fix it?

**function.php** file

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'themename' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'themename' ),
    ) );
```

**Header.php** file

```
    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) 

       'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
       'container'          => 'nav',
       'container_class'    => 'navbar navbar-default',
       'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
; ?>
        <?php
    if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary_navigation_menu' ) ) {
         wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary_navigation_menu' ) );
    } ?>

        <?php if ( is_home() ): ?>
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) : ?>
     //primary menu
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

P.S. Both of my menu bar are different CSS.

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Wordpress menu on specific pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419166/display-wordpress-menu-on-specific-pages)

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Hmm, I think is quite similar but I don't get the answer. Can you explain it?

Comment: I have added my answer if you do not get it please ask question there .

Comment: @R3y. I have added the answer as you required. Pls check it.

Comment: @R3y. I have modified my code and your `header.php` should look like what i have provided. Ensure that you write all the other codes needed for the registering the menu to be in `functions.php` file. Don't mess up with the codes over to the `header.php`. Be precise in coding and have fun..

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in conditionals Wordpress provides:

- `is_home()` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/
- `is_front_page()` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

If you have set your home page to display your latest posts then you should use `is_home()`, if you've set your home page as the front page through `Reading > Settings > Front page displays`, then you should use `is_front_page()`.

Wrap those menu functions in a conditional statement that's applicable to your case.

You could also combine them:

```
<?php 
    if ( !(is_front_page() || is_home()) ) {
       wp_nav_menu( array( 
       'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
       'container'          => 'nav',
       'container_class'    => 'navbar navbar-default',
       'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
       ) ); 
    }

?>
```

The above conditional statement will return `true` if the page in question isn't the home page or the front page.

You can also use the `is_page()` conditional tag to check any other page.

- `is_page()` -
  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

This function allows you to pass an optional parameter in its parenthesis to target a specific page, or number of pages using (int|string|array) Page ID, title, slug, or array.

Comment: Add also for about us page , he wants secondary menu for both home page as well as about us page .

Comment: Doesn't seem like it: "...What I'm try to do is show my primary menu bar only in my main home page, and show secondary menu on my about us page, services page, etc"

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError It showed error on my localhost but i tried this code

Comment: @R3y is the primary menu will be totally remain absent in other pages ?

Comment: @R3y a bit of a syntax error with the example code there, I've since rectified that (changed `is_frontpage` to `is_front_page`). I'd recommend simply echoing a string to test out those conditionals before implementing them. E.g: `if(is_front_page()) {echo "is front page";}`

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu the error just disappear, my main home page now is only left one menu bar, but my about us page (etc..) still have 2 menu bar..

Comment: @R3y check my answer or the comment I have added to Naresh's answer .

Comment: @R3y Why don't you just wrap your primary menu function in a similar conditional statement that evaluates `true` if it `is_front_page()` or `is_home()`? It's literally just copy and pasting and removing the `!()` negation wrapping those two conditional statements. I've also provided links to these references, you should have everything you need to achieve what you're aiming for, and this would be a good opportunity to get yourself more familiar with these conditional tags.

Comment: @R3y UncaughttypeError is very correct with his suggestion for you .

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Yup, you are right. I am still a new coder this thing is difficult to me. Anyway thank you for you answer..

Comment: We all start somewhere, @R3y, goodluck! The wordpress codex really helped me in the beginning. You'll still find a lot of help here at stackoverflow.com, wordpress.stackexchange.com as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the secondary menu in the page that you wish alone.
By using the is_page() you can display the menu where ever you want.

// When any single Page is being displayed.

```
is_page();
```

// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.

```
is_page( 42 );
```

// When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.

```
is_page( 'Contact' );
```

// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

```
is_page( 'about-me' );
```

For Example if you are going to display secondary menu in all the pages except  `home` page you can have the code like this.

```
<?php
if (!is_home())
{
   // Here you can display the Secondary menu
  if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary-menu' ) ) { /* if menu location 'secondary-menu' exists then use custom menu */
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary-menu') ); 
}     
else
{
   // here you can display the primary menu.
   if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) { /* if menu location 'primary-menu' exists then use custom menu */
  wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu') ); 
}    
?>
```

Now the primary menu will be displayed only in about-me page alone.

is_page() supports array too:

```
if( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) )
     //either in about us, or contact, or management page is in view
else
     //none of the page about us, contact or management is in view
```

**Replace your `header.php` as i have provided below.**

Your Header.php needs to be changed like this. You write all the other codes for registering the menu and others in function.php file don't mix it up here in `header.php` file.

```
<?php
        if(is_home() || is_front_page()) // This ensures that the below part execute for home page or front page alone
        {
                if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) { 
                /* if menu location 'primary-menu' exists then use custom menu */
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu') ); 
                }    
        }
        else
        {
                if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary_navigation_menu' ) ) {
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary_navigation_menu' ) );
                }
        }
?>
```

Comment: How to combine all this code? Can you show me detail a bit?

Comment: @NareshKumar.P how many pages he can add like ```if( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) )``` better would be using ```if ( ! is_home() )``` instead .

Comment: Ya you can do that . I have given him an Example that you can try out like this to since some idea may strike to him if he sees a bit more clear..

Answer (score 0):

If you go through your header.php there should be something like this .

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) : ?>
```

Now in your functions.php register another menu location

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'secondary_menu' => 'Secondary Navigation Menu',
    'secondary_navigation_menu' => 'My Custom Footer Menu',
) );
```

and after `if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) : ?>`  section there should be code to display menu something like

```
 wp_nav_menu( array( 
       'theme_location'    => 'secondary',
       'container'          => 'nav',.......
```

after this add

```
<?php
    if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary_navigation_menu' ) ) {
         wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary_navigation_menu' ) );
    } ?>
```

now for displaying primary menu only in home page wrap is_home() like

```
<?php if ( is_home() ): ?>
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) : ?>
     //primary menu
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

if you want your primary menu not to appear on home page do like

```
<?php if ( ! is_home() ): ?>
    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary_navigation_menu' ) : ?>
         //secondarymenu
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: @R3y I have added pages functions.php and header.php. you need to make a child theme and override header.php and add the some code to functions.php as I have mentioned .

Comment: (Sorry for so many questions here as i am still new coder) So my final code should be like how?

Comment: @R3y in your functions.php add ```register_nav_menus``` and rest code belongs to header.php .

Comment: @R3y if you know gist or pastebin add your header.php code to any of these and provide the link to me .

Comment: Something like this? <?php if ( is_home() ): ?>
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' )
wp_nav_menu( array(
                'container'   => 'nav',
                'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
                'menu_class'  => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'
     ) );

 ? but i got error not sure how to but those wp_nav_menu( array( between them

Comment: @R3y what error you got ? have you add your code to gist or pastebin then provide link.

Comment: in your comment ```if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ``` should be ```if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ): ```

Comment: @R3y which theme you are using ?

Comment: i got syntax error and i am helping my client creating the theme.

Comment: @R3y what syntax error you got is because of your code my code does not conatins syntax error .

Comment: I just post my code on the add answer below.  Can you  correct  / edit it if my code is wrong?  Or it is  the correct  way to add the code like  this way?

Comment: @R3y I can not see your answer, do not use this site as code editor, better to use pastebin or gist .

Comment: @R3y your code reflects you have no idea of coding, please learn basic php before coding this type of things, sorry but no one can help you if you are coding like that .